# Using Multiset to count occurrences

Tags: java, guava

I'm currently using a Multiset to hold a maximum of three numbers. I need to check if:

1. A number appears more than once
2. A number and another number appear the same amount of times
3. There is only one number
4. The list is empty

Below is my current code. In this case, team is a Multimap and points is the Multiset:

```
for(int a = 0; a <= team.keySet().size(); a++)
{
    if(points.count(a) > 1)
    {
    // Point 1
    }
    else if(points.size == 1)
    {
    // Point 3
    }
    else if(points.isEmpty()
    {
    // Point 4
    }
}
```

I'm stuck as to how I would implement Point 2 - any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

How about :

```
Multiset<Integer> tmp = HashMultiset.create();
for(int a = 0; a <= team.keySet().size(); a++) {
  tmp.add(points.count(a));
}
```

Now see if tmp has a value with count() > 1

Answer (score 0):

Before the `for`-loop, declare a
`Map<Integer,Boolean> numEntries = new HashMap<Integer,Boolean>();`
This map will contain a `true` *value* if some number a has *key* entries.
Then, after the last `else if` you could add:

```
if (numEntries.containsKey(points.count(a)) && numEntries.get(points.count(a)){
    //Point 2, some other number has already had this number of entries
} else {
    numEntries.put(points.count(a), true); // a has this number of entries!
    //Or do something more complicated to save that it was the number a that
    //"was here first" (you could change the value type from Boolean to Integer
    //or something to save this information)
}
```

With pretty heavy use of points.count(a), I would consider making it a local variable.

**Edit** Had faulty logic before, above code should now behave properly

Answer (score 0):

I really don't understand why are you doing for loop on Multimap's keySet size and then checking count on incremented counter...

That's why I assume you mentioned `Multimap` because you want obtain `Multiset` from [`Multimap#keys()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html#keys%28%29). Here you have example code:

```
final class MultisetFromMultimap {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Multimap<Integer, Integer> team = ImmutableMultimap.of(
        1, 1,
        1, 2,
        2, 22,
        2, 33,
        3, 0);
    test(team, 2, 1);
    test(ImmutableMultimap.of(42, 42), 42, 1);
    test(ImmutableMultimap.<Integer, Integer>of(), 0, 1);
  }

  private static void test(Multimap<Integer, Integer> team,
      Integer test1, Integer test2) {
    System.out.println("multimap: " + team);
    Multiset<Integer> points = team.keys();
    System.out.println("multiset: " + points);

    boolean ad1 = points.count(test1) > 1; // point 1
    boolean ad2 = points.count(test1) == points.count(test2); // point 2
    boolean ad3 = points.size() == 1; // point 3
    boolean ad4 = points.isEmpty(); // point 4
    System.out.println("answers: " + Arrays.asList(ad1, ad2, ad3, ad4));
  }
}
```

which yields following output:

```
multimap: {1=[1, 2], 2=[22, 33], 3=[0]}
multiset: [1 x 2, 2 x 2, 3]
answers: [true, true, false, false]
multimap: {42=[42]}
multiset: [42]
answers: [false, false, true, false]
multimap: {}
multiset: []
answers: [false, true, false, true]
```